# I can't create my signup route with postman

Tags: javascript, postman

exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {

```
User.findOne({
    attributes: ['mail'],
    where: {  
        mail: req.body.mail
    }
})
.then(userExist => {
    if(!userExist) {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        .then(hash => {
            const user = User.build({
                username: req.body.username,
                mail: req.body.mail,
                password: hash,
                admin: 0
            });
            user.save()
                .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Votre compte a bien été créé !' }))
                .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error: '⚠ Oops, une erreur s\'est produite !' }));
        })
        .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error: 'Une erreur s\'est produite lors de la création de votre compte' }));
    } else {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Cet utilisateur existe déjà' })
    }
})
.catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error: '⚠ Oops, une erreur s\'est produite !' }));
```

};

Postman :

[image: Test Signup route]

I tested my route with json format.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: The problem is that you should console log the err in the catch block after then and you might get more idea about the eroor

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message @Vikash :

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
        "parent": {
            "code": "ER_DATA_TOO_LONG",
            "errno": 1406,
            "sqlState": "22001",
            "sqlMessage": "Data too long for column 'password' at row 1",
            "sql": "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`username`,`mail`,`password`,`admin`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?);",
            "parameters": [
                "jeantille",
                "jeantille@gmail.com",
                "$2b$10$gk0mK6NbtM5GGnUK/a2Qj.wmYpMElYMWnEC.zwiCtUB32smi7HXkm",
                0,
                "2022-08-12 03:39:55",
                "2022-08-12 03:39:55"
            ]
        },
        "original": {
            "code": "ER_DATA_TOO_LONG",
            "errno": 1406,
            "sqlState": "22001",
            "sqlMessage": "Data too long for column 'password' at row 1",
            "sql": "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`username`,`mail`,`password`,`admin`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?);",
            "parameters": [
                "jeantille",
                "jeantille@gmail.com",
                "$2b$10$gk0mK6NbtM5GGnUK/a2Qj.wmYpMElYMWnEC.zwiCtUB32smi7HXkm",
                0,
                "2022-08-12 03:39:55",
                "2022-08-12 03:39:55"
            ]
        },
        "sql": "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`username`,`mail`,`password`,`admin`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?);",
        "parameters": [
            "jeantille",
            "jeantille@gmail.com",
            "$2b$10$gk0mK6NbtM5GGnUK/a2Qj.wmYpMElYMWnEC.zwiCtUB32smi7HXkm",
            0,
            "2022-08-12 03:39:55",
            "2022-08-12 03:39:55"
        ]
    }
}
```

It's looks like SQL doesn't want to take the values because the data is too long. Thanks you @Vikash.